# Loop storing 1s complement

Tags: binary

Suppose a computer uses 4-bit one’s complement numbers. Ignoring overflows, what value will be stored in the variable j after the following pseudocode routine terminates?

```
0 → j // Store 0 in j
-3 → k // Store -3 in k
while k ≠ 0
    j = j + 1 
    k = k - 1 
end while
```

'''

I thought the loop would continue forever, but the answer in the back of the book says:

```
J (Binary) K (Binary) 
0   0000  -3   1100
1   0001  -4   1011 (1100 + 1110) (where last carry is added to sum doing 1's complement addition)
2   0010  -5   1010 (1011 + 1110)
3   0011  -6   1001 (1010 + 1110)
4   0100  -7   1000 (1001 + 1110)
5   0101   7   0111 (1000 + 1110) (This is overflow -- but you can ignore)
6   0110   6   0110
7   0111   5   0101
-7  1000   4   0100
-6  1001   3   0011
-5  1010   2   0010
-4  1011   1   0001
-3  1100   0   0000
```

I do not understand how the k can flip to positives and the j to negatives. I do understand how they got the rows of where j =0,1,2,3,4

Comment: If the loop *did* continue forever, it would imply k was never treated as 0.. yet 4 bits has a finite set of values, so the only way it *could* continue forever is if k *stopped* decrementing at some point *or* 'looped' back to a negative integer while skipping 0. Thus for the loop to stop it has to be some sequence -1,-2,..,0 (and it is, which is why the loop is not infinite).

Comment: Another way: if 0 is in the data-type domain (ie k_bits=0000), and a decrement (or increment) operation is guaranteed to iterate through the all values as a sequence, then 0 will be trivially reached before such a sequence loops. The j variable is interesting to observe, while being independent of k.